# Multivariable Complex Analysis Book

Tags: complex-analysis

Can anyone recommend me a book that covers the topic of complex analysis (mostly integral calculus) of functions with more than one variable?

Comment: what about complex variables and applications by brown and churchill

Comment: seek thru https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Several+complex+variables+books&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8.

Comment: You might take a look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31395/functions-of-several-complex-variables-book-recommendations